# Were there in the USSR monasteries decorated with Soviet orders?

Tags: soviet-union, church

Were there in the USSR monasteries decorated with Soviet decorations, particularly, the Order of the Red Banner?

Comment: Why do you think there could be such a thing?

Comment: @Felix Goldberg absolutely no idea. But I heard from somebody that he was in an "Order of the Red Banner XXX monastery". I have no idea whether it was serious or a joke. On the other hand, why not given that people were working in the monasteries and also they possibly contributed during WWII.

Comment: @Almost certainly a joke. Here is an example of jocular usage: http://wwwbloggercomerizo1947.blogspot.co.il/2012/08/blog-post_6053.html

Answer (score 15):

## Impossible

No religious *institution* has ever been decorated by the Soviet government.
I do not have a definitive proof (that would require searching through all the decoration records, which, given the [fantastic generosity in decorations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders,_decorations,_and_medals_of_the_Soviet_Union) - tens of millions decorations awarded - is beyond my capabilities), but I am quite confident that this has never happened, even though I can understand the doubts someone who never lived in the USSR might have.

When thinking about USSR and its ideology, one has to remember the motto "We do not penny-pinch on ideology" - "На идеологии мы не экономим". Ideological concepts were taken quite seriously - only the need for the atomic bomb [saved quantum mechanics](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/14700/1979), and, despite chronic food shortages, [genetics was still condemned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lysenkoism).

Until 1943, all religious institutions and their "officers" were treated as enemies and persecuted at any opportunity.

The official phraseology underwent a major shift from "internationalism" to "patriotism" during the WW2, including letting the church elect a patriarch and [accepting donations from it](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%28%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%29), as well as decorating some individual priests.

However, the idea of decorating a church **institution** still is preposterous.

The reason is that the Soviet ideology invested organizations and institutions with a certain degree of sanctity (this is actually the reason why [Kamenev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lev_Kamenev)/[Zinoviev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grigory_Zinoviev)/[Buharin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikolai_Bukharin) &c were *not* exonerated in 1950-ies together with lesser victims - because they were condemned not just by the courts, which could err, but also by the **party** - which is *infallible*).

Similarly, decorating an **individual** priest says "*even though he is confused and brainwashed by a retrograde ideology, he did the right thing and we recognize that*".

However, decorating a church **institution** legitimizes it ideologically, so it was completely unacceptable to the Soviet officialdom.

Therefore, even if a monastery did something good in the eyes of the Soviet government, they would never decorate it, they would decorate the *individuals* responsible (e.g., monks). An example is the decoration of [Alexy I](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexy_I_of_Moscow) with the [Order of the Red Banner of Labour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_the_Red_Banner_of_Labour) for his participation in the attack on the [Ukrainian Greek Catholic Church](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_Greek_Catholic_Church) in 1946 - the *person* was decorated, not the *institution* he lead.

## Folklore

I think what you heard ("Order of the Red Banner XXX monastery" - "краснознамённый XXX монастырь"/"ордена красного знамени XXX монастырь") was a joke.

This was actually a very common theme in the Soviet folklore, playing on the officialdom's frequent abuse the "organization decorations", e.g., ["Ленинградский ордена Ленина метрополитен имени В. И. Ленина"](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD) (**Leningrad's** of order of **Lenin** subway named after **Lenin**).

It was used to imply that the entity in question was important and well known (as well as "recognized by the government as legitimate"). 
E.g., one could say "московская трижды краснознамённая хоральная синагога" ("moscow choral synagogue thrice decorated by the red banner order") to emphasize its official standing with the soviet bureaucracy, as opposed to a group of Jews (secretly) praying together in a random basement.

Another common joke was referring to arbitrary cities as [hero-city](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hero_City) (e.g., "город-герой Нью-Йорк" - "hero-city New York").
In fact, the [search for the term on the popular Russian joke site](https://www.anekdot.ru/search/?query=%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9&ch%5Bo%5D=on&mode=all&xcnt=20&maxlen=0&order=0) reveals the following "hero cities":

- [Bishkek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bishkek)
- [Dolgoprudny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolgoprudny)
- Amsterdam
- [Sharm El Sheikh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharm_El_Sheikh)
- [Yessentuki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yessentuki)
- Hamburg
- Oakland
- Washington
- [Strezhevoy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strezhevoy)
- Hongkong
- London
- New York
- many more, I am too lazy...

Comment: Not "краснознаменный монастырь", but "Ордена Красного Знамени ххх монастырь"

Comment: Well this does not sound that jokingly given that the patriarch Alexis I was decorated with the Red Banner Order in 1946.

Comment: Note that any monastery was also a fort and a workshop so they could theoretically contribute during WWII, especially given that the monasteries have an extensive history of supporting the Russian military during the wars. One can speculate that a monastery could successfully defend against a siege or they could contribute in another fashion (providing industrial production, food or curing the wounded).

Comment: @Anixx: same difference "краснознаменный" & "Ордена Красного Знамени". See edit.

Comment: You did not answer the question. Monasteries were NOT decorated with Soviet orders. As organizations.

Comment: @Alex: that's exactly what I said: "impossible". Please read the answer again.

Comment: @Alex yet there were monasteries decorated with non-state orders. For example, the Korets monastery was decorated with Order of Saint Prince Vladimir of 1st degree in 1980, the order being instituted in 1957.

Comment: @Anixx: that's the [church's own order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_St._Vladimir), not wonder it is decorating its in own institutions with it.

Comment: краснознамённый does not mean decorated by the red banner order.

Answer (score 3):

No, they were not. Church was an "[opium for the folk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opium_of_the_people)" so church institutions could not deserve to be decorated with respected symbols of communism. This Marx phrase was the official view.

Soviet regime was strong enough on its own. There was no need for it to accept any help from religious institutions, even if offered. And the official negative position was firm enough so that voluntary decoration with such symbols was unlikely to be helpful.

Comment: Any source?....

Comment: "opium of the people" is said by Marx. Nobody decorates drugs with national symbols, does not make any sense. Putting American flag on the illegal drug can will not soften the hearth of the American policeman.

Comment: Religion was legal.

Comment: Many things are legal, but are not honored by the state.