# What percentage of people were acquitted in "Stalin's trials"

Tags: soviet-union, 1930s, 1940s, 1950s

What proportion of those accused under Article 58 and other political articles were acquitted in 1930-1953 in the USSR?

Comment: In Stalin's time practically no one.  Formal acquittal would endanger judges and prosecutors themselves. Even people who were released from GULAG (to due war needs for example) did not had their sentences revoked until after Stalin's death. Sentence was there to be used if that person again becomes "unreliable" in Stalinist system.

Comment: @rs.29 at Shakhty trial, 4 of 53 were acquitted.

Comment: @user31264  I believe we should differ between the purges of the 30s there Stalin got rid of competitors in the party itself and the army and the earlier ones.

Comment: There are known cases where the date of the verdict accidentally contained the date it was typed, which was before trial started.

Comment: @user31264 This was in 1928, before Stalin got full power. Also those acquitted in the trial were German specialists, all except one who was latter rearrested and sentenced.

Comment: @rs.29 How about at least Rokossovsky ? What are you talking about?

Comment: As far as I know, when Yezhov fell, there were numerous acquittals. I don't have time to provide any sources, since that I won't post an answer. But I'm sure there were tens of percents of those who had been convicted. So, ironically, if Stalin killed 99 billion, it must be tens of billions acquitted.

Comment: **Though if your question is about acquittals only on trials, not later**, then I don't know, actually

Comment: @DmitryKoroliov Rokossovsky was not acquitted, he was simply released from prison. Same happened to many - their sentenced remained formally "active" throughout Stalin's life.

Comment: @rs.29 where did you get this from? This is not a rhetoric question, I indeed wonder. I couldn't find a reliable source, that he was acquitted too, but for me it's more likely, since it's just ridiculous that someone can be 'just released'. Even in Dudayev's Chechnya in 1994, when they took Russian tank crews as prisoners/bandits (since they didn't have any insignia etc.) they refused to 'simply release' them, w/o following some formalities, which in that case was Dudayev's pardon, which was jerry-rigged in last moment before the release

Comment: @DmitryKoroliov: More precisely, the case against Rokossovsky, after several delays  was "terminated" and R. was released. He was even given a "release document" confirming his situation. See page 70 [here](http://prussia.online/Data/Book/tr/tribunal-dlya-geroev/%D0%97%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2%20%D0%92.%20%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%93%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B2.pdf).

Comment: @DmitryKoroliov Well, as you said yourself, there is no official document of his acquittal. There is official document about his investigation (следственное дело № 25358-1937) and  there is certainly some NKVD note about his release.  Comparing Stalin's "legal system" with modern Russian legal system is a no go. Note that even after Rokossovsky was released, his rank was not fully restored (that happened only later). As I said, this was common practice during Stalin, look for example what happened to Polikarpov, never fully rehabilitated until 1956, long after his death.

Comment: @rs.29 `as you said yourself, there is no official document of his acquittal` **where did I say this**? I said I failed to find a reliable source, since I didn't go to the archive, can you imagine?

Comment: @MoisheKohan thank you for the information.

Comment: though I wouldn't call it 'simply released', rather something like: *the prosecution had not found enough evidence or for whatever reason decided to drop the case against Rokossovsky*

Answer (score 9):

## What were "Stalin's trials"?

If you want to limit the discussion to the few "show trials", like [Шахтинское дело](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE) or "Московские процессы" ([1](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81), [2](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81), [3](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81)), you can compute that from the public information and get something like 1%. These were well scripted events and acquittals were limited to some foreigners (e.g., Germans at the Shakhty) and specific stunts ("see, this is a real trial, we even acquitted X" - to execute him after the next trial).

## 1927 - 1955, all political cases: 0%

"Convictions" vs "Acquittals" were meaningless in these cases.

This was *not* how the Soviet "judiciary" operated, especially during Stain's years. It was a system *not* of meting out punishments for crimes, but for fulfilling the government needs for free labor in GULAG (aka "industrial armies" prescribed by the [Communist Manifesto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Communist_Manifesto)).

A funny tidbit: the huge article [Сталинские репрессии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8) does not even *mention* the word "acquittal" ;-)

### post-Stalin

Later on (after the [20th congress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/20th_Congress_of_the_Communist_Party_of_the_Soviet_Union)), the court proceedings became more meaningful (see, e.g., [Дело мальчиков](https://diletant.media/articles/38416324/)), but only in some criminal (non-political) cases.

E.g., consider [Rokotov-Faibishenko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rokotov-Faibishenko_case):
this was in 1960, and an entirely *economic* (not political!) case.
However, the perpetrators were tried on a [ex post facto law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_post_facto_law) (expressly forbidden by all Soviet constitutions) [3(!) times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_bis_in_idem) and were sentenced to *death*.

## Standard Operating Procedure

### "Thinking"

The "Soviet thinking" during Stalin's years went like this:

- [Chekist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheka): Anyone can be suspected
- Prosecutor: A suspicion by Chekists is sufficient grounds for an arrest warrant
- Judge: An arrest is a conclusive proof of guilt

While looking caricaturish, these principles were accepted by "everyone", coalescing into the adage "*у нас зря не сажают*" ("*our system does not imprison people for nothing*").

### "Working"

#### Chekist

A [CheKa/GPU/NKVD(&c)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KGB) operative was a high status government official: well paid, fed, clothed; permitted to carry a gun. He was feared and respected. He valued his job.

His job performance was evaluated on how many people he brought to trial.
To catch his quota of ["enemies of the people"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enemy_of_the_people), he used many informers who reported on their social and workplace acquaintances: some to get rid of rivals or arbitrary vindictiveness, others out of genuine love for the country/political idealism &c.

Given "агентурные материалы" (agents' material reports, e.g., "John Doe said that he was not paid fairly" or "Jane Doe thinks(!) that she is better than the party secretary"), he has no choice to ask for an arrest warrant and interrogate the suspect, asking for evidence on more people. If he did not, he would have been accused of "political myopia" and arrested himself.

#### Prosecutor & Judge (and ["кивалы"/"nodders"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C))

##### *ты что,* **органам** *не доверяешь?!*

This question (*what, you do not trust the security apparatus*?!) was very dangerous. If you do not backpedal right away, you *will* find yourself on the receiving end of the "justice" system.

## Finally

This question reminds me of another one ([Were there in the USSR monasteries decorated with Soviet orders?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/11493/1979)) - both betray complete ignorance of Soviet realities.
This is *not* to belittle the questioners, of course, but to underscore how effective Soviet propaganda was.

Comment: *the huge article Сталинские репрессии does not even mention the word "acquittal"* If you looked in an article named like 'правосудие во времена Сталина' (Justice during Stalin's period) instead of the 'Stalin repressions' you would definitely find the word 'acquittal'. Seriously, the word 'repressions' doesn't even imply impartiality

Comment: @DmitryKoroliov: (1) the question is about Stalin's repressions, not general Soviet Justice system (2) implying that the word "repressions" is not applicable to Stalin's regime does not demonstrate your impartiality.

Comment: I read that the number was as high as 10% or more (https://news.rambler.ru/other/41149727-pochemu-pri-staline-sudy-vynosili-tak-mnogo-opravdatelnyh-prigovorov/) For comparison, the modern Russia, the rate of acquitals in court in 2018 was 0.25%.  In the modern USA, the rate of acquitals in court in 2019 was 0.4% for federal crimes (https://www.doarlaw.com/blog/2021/04/what-you-should-know-about-the-federal-governments-conviction-rate/)

Comment: That 10% number of acquittals, however, includes all trials, political and purely criminal, and does not include troikas.

Comment: @user31264: Please, read the first text you quote more closely. They only mention termination of investigations by NKVD and by the local public prosecutor's office, **not** an acquittal at a trial.

Comment: @user31264: The rambler article is quite incoherent, adjacent sentences often contradict each other.

Comment: @user31264 It may be that the low rate of acquittals for U.S. Federal crimes is due to the DOJ not prosecuting unless they believe they have a very strong, pretty much guaranteed case. For example Jan. 6th slam dunk misdemeanors vs sedition charges. I hope not really comparable to the Stalinist courts.

Comment: @MickeyfAgain_BeforeExitOfSO One should also take into account that in 90% of the federal cases the defendant pleads guilty beforehand and the case never goes to trial.

Comment: @MoisheKohan in Stalin's trials, most of defendants also pleaded guilty.

Comment: @user31264: For a different reason.

Comment: @MickeyfAgain_BeforeExitOfSO nope, it's largely because of plea bargains. Threaten the victim with a trial for something even worse and they'll cave to the lesser charges. So threaten them with a capital crime like attempted murder of congresspeople or overthrowing the state, then have them sign a confession to criminal tresspassing with intent to destroy property instead. That's the joke that's the US "justice" system.